# Paypal: payment timeout

Tags: paypal

We are using the "Website Payments Standard" method and now we would like to set a timeout (30 minutes) on our customer payments. In other words the customer must complete the payment registration within 30 minutes, otherwise he must do the process all over again.

My issue is that I can´t find and variables in the API that fit my needs.

Does anyone have a solution for this issue?

Answer (score 3):

see: https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/forums/adaptive-payments-api/cancel-or-timeout-payment

> At this time, there is not a way to cancel a paykey and a timeout value cannot be specified.  The default timeout value for PayPal is 5 minutes (after being inactive) however a paykey is good for 3 hours.  So if the user were to copy the redirect url (before logging in), that url (with paykey) would be good for 3 hours.

So...there is no solution :(

Answer (score 0):

If you switch to Website Payments Pro, you could have more control over this (where final payment is taken on your site, not Paypal's), but there isn't a way with Standard because they leave your site and if they return, it's only after they have paid..

Answer (score 0):

Just to be simple, you cannot have a timeout in Standard mode but you can have it in Pro mode.